# multi-directory "make" in linux programming

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

suppose we have a file-list:

- src

  - a
  - b
  - c
- Makefile

and there are many .cc & .h files in each folders.
how to write the Makefile??

when I write a path like this
./a/a.cc or ../a/a.cc

errors will be occurred.

but when i put the files on the same directory
and write as a.cc.
everything is ok.

I run it on cygwin.
could anyone help me?

Comment: Posting an example of your makefile would be helpful.

Comment: should work with ./a/a.cc but you have to make sure that the dependencies are correct. A Makefile never changes the working directory

Comment: potentially duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9313760/1025391

Answer (score 1):

The `wildcard` function is what you are looking for: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html

On Linux I would prefer Automake/Autoconf build systems: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System

An alternative could be CMake: http://www.cmake.org/

Comment: I'm a newcomer. Stackoverflow is really an excellent website that gathered the most high-level geeks in the whole world. These answers are quite useful and I accepted them all. Has anyone receive it?

Comment: Thanks for your constructive advice~

Answer (score 1):

From the not-so-clear directory graph, it seems that you are missing the `src/` directory prefix in your `Makefile`. E.g. to compile `src/a/a.cc`, use:

```
src/a/a.o: src/a/a.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

**BUT**: Do yourself a favour, and use a real build system, such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org). It is cross-platform, can generate IDE project files (e.g. for Visual Studio, Xcode, Eclipse, CodeBlocks, etc.), is much higher level and does automatic dependency tracking for you.

Answer (score 1):

You've left out a lot of details (e.g. where you want to put the object files), but `VPATH` is probably what you're looking for.

```
VPATH = src/a src/b src/c

# Now you can write rules as if the .cc & .h files were in the current directory.

%.o: %.cc
    do something with $<

foo.o: foo.cc bar.h
    do something special with $<
```